# Carousel stops after last slide and doesn't cycle

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am making a site for a client and using bootstrap to build a carousel. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 for this. I looked on here for a similar situation to mine, but the two similar cases I found have no answers to them.

Here's the url: http://realtormatchaz.com/

Everything is working fine, except in the js there must be something stopping the carousel from cycling when it hits the last slide. Pretty sure this is a simple fix but I'm not too great at js yet.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any code!

EDIT:

Honestly the only thing I changed from the original bootstrap js was the interval

```
Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
interval: 7000, 
pause: 'hover',
wrap: true
}
```

Here's the code for the markup:

```
<div id="main-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active span12">
          <div class="slider-imagery fadeIn fadeIn-3s fadeIn-Delay-3s">
            <img src="http://realtormatchaz.com/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/img/slider-1.png" width="100%" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item span12">
          <div class="slider-imagery fadeIn fadeIn-3s fadeIn-Delay-3s">
            <img src="http://realtormatchaz.com/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/img/slider-2.png" width="100%"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
      </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where's the carousel?

Comment: The... slider on top? It's a carousel...

Comment: Now it's cycling but cutting out halfway through the transition... I'm like just proficient enough to be dangerous I think haha

Comment: Honestly the only thing I changed from the original bootstrap js was the interval

    Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 7000
  , pause: 'hover'
  , wrap: true
  }

Comment: And if you remove any of those does the problem go away? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. I took out the fades so you guys can see what's happening better.

Answer (score 0):

When I load the page I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

It seems that `$` isn't in scope, which is probably because [the DOM isn't ready yet](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Try wrapping it like this:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
  });
});
```